# Express & Vue: How to automatically update MongoDB database on POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am quite new to Node JS, I decided to create a small application

The structure of my project is very simple, I have a catalog of books, When I click on the **add book** button, I process the POST request then add the book to the database, My problem is that when I try to add the book to the database,

I want to reactively update the state of my array to display my new product, but instead I have to close the connection to the server and then zone enable refresh my page, and then I will see my newly added product, At the same time, the status of my POST request is always `pending`

**index.vue**

```
<div v-for="book in books" :key="book._id">
   ...


  fetch("http://localhost:3000/addedBook", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**index.js**

```
app.post('/addedBook', (req, res) => {
  coll.insertOne(req.body, (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
      mongoClient.close();
    } else {
      console.log('error', err)
    }
  });
```

Comment: **(1)** `coll.insertOne(req.body, (err, res) => { ` - change this to `coll.insertOne(req.body, (err, result) => {...` **(2)** `if (!err) { mongoClient.close(); ` - change this to `if (!err) { console.log('Insert result:', result); res.send(result) } else {... `

Comment: Also refer the MongoDB NodeJS API documentation at: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/

Answer (score 0):

**Index.vue**

```
  fetch("/addedBook", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      this.books.push(result)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**Index.js**

```
app.post('/addedBook', (req, res) => {
    let db = mongo.db("books");
    let collection = db.collection("books");
    collection.insertOne(req.body, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('');
            return
        }
        res.send(req.body) //retruns the new document
    })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).